# Is courtroom procedure on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about courtroom procedures in specific circumstances, but I'm not sure if that is on-topic based on what I can see in the asking help. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Existing applicable tags might include [process](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process), [court](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/court), [rules-of-court](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-court), [rules-of-evidence](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-of-evidence), [voir-dire](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voir-dire), [judge](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judge), [jury](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jury)....